# Broken Package error on update

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies

While updating the Ubuntu 20.04, I am getting the following error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libsystemd0_245.4-4ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The system was running 19.10, and was recently upgraded to 20.04.

The result of `sudo apt autoremove` is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsystemd0 : Breaks: libsystemd0:i386 (!= 245.4-4ubuntu3.1) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.2 is installed
 libsystemd0:i386 : Breaks: libsystemd0 (!= 245.4-4ubuntu3.2) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.1 is installed
 libudev1 : Breaks: libudev1:i386 (!= 245.4-4ubuntu3.1) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.2 is installed
 libudev1:i386 : Breaks: libudev1 (!= 245.4-4ubuntu3.2) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.1 is installed
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 245.4-4ubuntu3.2) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.1 is installed
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 245.4-4ubuntu3.2) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The result of `sudo apt install libsystemd0` is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libudev1 : Breaks: libudev1:i386 (!= 245.4-4ubuntu3.1) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
 libudev1:i386 : Breaks: libudev1 (!= 245.4-4ubuntu3.2) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 245.4-4ubuntu3.2) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have added any PPAs to your software sources.list that are causing so many version conflicts remove them and restore Ubuntu's default software repositories with [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017/). Then update the software sources with `sudo apt update`.

Remove the cached libsystemd0 .deb file that is generating the error message and reinstall libsystemd0 and libudev1.

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libsystemd0_245.4-4ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb # If this command results in a warning ignore the warning.
sudo apt update # try to update again
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo apt remove libsystemd0:i386 libudev1:i386 libsystemd0 libudev1
sudo apt --fix-broken install 
sudo apt install libsystemd0 libudev1
```